# Why won't the moderators delete my account?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Because I have asked more than one question, I cannot simply click 'delete'. I have asked them in a private message and have used the account deactivation form twice but with no response. This was 20 hours ago.

I wonder if the moderators' refusal to grant my request is a vindictive response to me asking workplace-related questions they do not like. In any case, please deactivate my other account

https://workplace.stackexchange.com/users/22789/hammond-druthers

(I'll be deactivated this one immediately after asking this question).

Thanks!

H-Druth

Comment: That seems unlikely. A more plausible scenario is that deleting an account is a dangerous operation with broad consequences that isn't (easily?) available, even to moderators.

Comment: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account

Comment: Another plausible scenario is that it's the weekend and the moderators aren't here at your beck and call, ready to snap to attention when you click your fingers.

Answer (score 5):

1. Moderators are not able to delete your account
2. The proper deletion procedure is [written in the help center](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/deleting-account)
3. Even through that procedure it takes over 24 hours

So the moderators won't delete your account because we can't.

Comment: Further, since it's a weekend (and, in the US where two of the three mods and most of the community managers live, a holiday weekend), there may be some delays.

Comment: To be clear, moderators *can* delete accounts; normally they *don't* because it leaves them holding the bag when someone decides to be an ass (yes, I've seen people complain that their account was deleted *in response to the same email chain where they asked for it to be deleted*, so this can become a real headache - that's why we have such an elaborate procedure built up around it...)